# AKS NGINX use static internal IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

I have an Kubernetes Cluster on Azure (AKS) running with NGINX as an ingress in front.
The installation of Nginx was quite simple:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

But by that, the Loadbalancer was created with a public IP. That's why I changed the service and added two annotations:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    loadBalancerIP: 10.29.30.250
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.10.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.41.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Now the LoadblancerIP is private. But is not the IP from the annotations.

My Subnet: **10.29.30.240/28**

Result:

```
$ sudo kubectl get svc --all-namespaces --watch
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
...
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.125.51   10.29.30.248   80:30158/TCP,443:32714/TCP   57s
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong way to specify a static IP address for the LoadBalancer. It should be like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.10.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.41.2
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.29.30.250     # here is the location for the special IP address
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-an-ip-address). Pay attention to which subnet you use, different or the same with the AKS cluster.